# Update index algolia

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm using Laravel 5.5 with Scout. I have an index in algolia using Documents and the users associated with theses Documents

```
class Documents extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
      $data = $this->toArray();

      // formatting relationship for algolia

      $data['users'] = $this->types->toArray();
      $data['document_type'] = $this->typeDocuments->name;
      return $data;
    }

    protected $fillable = array('name', 'description', 'document_type');

    public function types() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Users', 'document_rights', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function typeDocuments() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Document_type', 'document_type');
    }
}
```

In my case, I will update one day the name of the Users, like this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = Users::find(5);
    $user->name = 'jean floriot';
    $user->update();
}
```

But it never changes the User in the index of Algolia. Any ideas how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the searchable() method for that. After `$this->update()` you will get something like:

```
App\Documents::where('user_id', '=', $this->id)->searchable();
```

Please let me know if that worked or if I missed something.

Comment: The problem is my user_id is in another table

Comment: Then you can adapt the query to use the pivot table: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-eloquent-how-to-query-pivot-table